# Android Espresso Synchronizing with Custom Resource

Tags: android, android-espresso

I want to use Espresso to test web calls. I've made a small test app to see if I can get this to work without using AsyncTask. Upon getting data back, a TextView tells the user whether the call was successful or not. I'm making the web call in a new thread.

In my test, I tried following the [AdvancedSynchronizationTest](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/source/browse/testapp_test/src/main/java/com/google/android/apps/common/testing/ui/testapp/AdvancedSynchronizationTest.java) as a pattern to making the test wait until the web request is fulfilled. My implementation, however, doesn't seem to work. My understanding is that the method that I'm overriding is ending before the callback is returned to the main activity. If that's the case, I'm overwriting the wrong class. I've also tried overriding runnable itself (see example below) and even changed the UI update to simply setting a boolean, but with no different outcome. Obviously, Espresso doesn't like my using another thread, but why doesn't it pick up that it should wait until the thread is complete? What would be an alternative without using AsyncTask?

You can see the whole project here: https://github.com/bqmackay/EspressoCustomThreadingResourceExample.

Here is the code in question:

MainActivityTest

```
public class MainActivityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity> {
...
    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        getActivity();

        Runnable runnable = getActivity().getDownloadHelper().getWebCallRunnable();
        CountingIdlingResource countingIdlingResource = new CountingIdlingResource("WebCallRunnableCall");
        getActivity().getDownloadHelper().setWebCallRunnable(new DecoratedWebCallRunnable(runnable, countingIdlingResource));
        registerIdlingResources(countingIdlingResource);
    }

    public void testThreadRetrieval() throws Exception {
        onView(withText("Thread")).perform(click());
        assertTrue(getActivity().isDidThreadReturn());
        //onView(withText("Thread Retrieved")).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
    }

    private class DecoratedWebCallRunnable implements Runnable {

        private final Runnable realRunnable;
        private final CountingIdlingResource countingIdlingResource;

        private DecoratedWebCallRunnable(Runnable realRunnable, CountingIdlingResource countingIdlingResource) {
            this.realRunnable = realRunnable;
            this.countingIdlingResource = countingIdlingResource;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            countingIdlingResource.increment();
            try {
                realRunnable.run();
            } finally {
                countingIdlingResource.decrement();
            }
        }
    }
```

DownloadHelper

```
public class DownloadHelper {
    private Runnable webCallRunnable;

    private Runnable createWebCallRunnable() {
        return new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = null;
            try {

                response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet("http://whoismyrepresentative.com/getall_mems.php?zip=84020"));
                StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
                if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
                    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
                    out.close();
                    repsCallbackInterface.onRepsThreadReceived(true);
                } else{
                    //Closes the connection.
                    response.getEntity().getContent().close();
                    repsCallbackInterface.onRepsThreadReceived(false);
                    throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        };
    }
}
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements RepsCallbackInterface {
    ....
    @Override
    public void onRepsThreadReceived(final boolean didReceive) {
        setDidThreadReturn(true);
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                threadText.setText(didReceive ? "Thread Retrieved" : "Thread Failed");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't really provide a question here, so I assume the question is about why this setup is not working as expected.

There are (at least) two reasons:

1. The assert `assertTrue(getActivity().isDidThreadReturn());`in `testThreadRetrieval()` does not wait at all for IdlingResources to be finished. Only `ViewInteraction.check()` and `ViewInteraction.perform()` are aware of those and will check IdlingResources before trying to apply the `ViewAssertion` or `ViewAction`.
2. Even if the commented out line after the `assertTrue()` is applied instead, it would not work, because the instrumentation thread is independent and doesn't wait for the new thread created in `getReps()` to start, so the check of IdlingResources can and will happen before the `CountingIdlingResource` is incremented.

If, for whatever reason, you really don't want to use an AsyncTask, you still can profit from Espresso watching the AsynTask thread pool by using its executor. So instead of starting a separate thread, just submit the Runnable to the `AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR`.

Comment: please if you have any project in android studio (gradle proj.) with working Idle resource, share with as on github, that would be real help for many people who struglle trying to make it work!